# ASP.Net Listview Eval time format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I can't seem to get the format right for an Eval statement in Label text in a Template on an ASP.Net Listview with VB.  I did try escaping the time but that still resulted in an invalid format.  The data type in the SQL Server for the bound data is time(0).

```
Text='<%# Eval("Time", "{0:hh:mm tt}") %>'
```

Has anyone run into this seemingly simply problem before and found the correct format?  I did research what is posted at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx but did not find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one had me tearing my hair out for a while... but I found the solution:

The second colon character needs to be escaped in your format string with a backslash.

Try this, it should work:

```
Text='<%# Eval("Time", "{0:hh\:mm}") %>'
```

Comment: "Unrecognized escape sequence" given by intellisense in markup.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"{0:hh.mm tt}")
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solve your problem.

```
Text='<%#String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"{0:hh:mm tt}",Eval("Time")) %>'
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add this to your label :

```
    DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" //display date only
    DataFormatString="{0:hh:mm tt}"  //display time only
    DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt}"  //display both date and time
    Text='<%# Eval("Time") %>'
```

also this link will help you alot for anykind of this problems

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx

Comment: DataFormatString can only be used in GridView not in ListView.